# React/Redux get the state from another component using store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I just started using Redux, as my application got complicated with the passing states to different component. I encountered an error while trying to retrieve data to another components.

I want to pass a state to another component, but I get this errror:

[image]

store.js

```
import {createStore} from 'redux';

const initialState = {
  regionId: 0
};
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

  if(action.type === "REGIONAL_ID") {
     return {
        regionId: action.regionId
      };
    }
    return state;
}
const store = createStore(reducer);
store.subscribe(() => {
  console.log(store.getState().regionId)
})

export default store;
```

In my Network.js component im calling this

```
const REGION_ID = store.subscribe(() => {
    return store.getState().regionId;
})
console.log(REGION_ID);
```

I tried the following but that gave me an error also. Many thanks!

```
const REGION_ID = return store.getState().regionId;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an error. The [**`store.subscribe()`**](https://redux.js.org/api-reference/store#subscribe-listener) method returns an `unsubscribe` method, and the `console.log()` displays the implementation of this method:

```
const REGION_ID = store.subscribe(() => {
    return store.getState().regionId; // this is isn't returned to REGION_ID
})
console.log(REGION_ID); // REGION_ID contains the unsubscribe method
```

If you want to use the the `regiondId` you get from the state place your code inside the subscribe callback:

```
tore.subscribe(() => {
    const REGION_ID = store.getState().regionId;
    console.log(REGION_ID );
})
```

This line `const REGION_ID = return store.getState().regionId;` produces an error because [you can't return outside of a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Bad_return_or_yield).

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks!

Comment: If you dont mind... How could I access the `REGION_ID` variable outside the subscribe function? That was the reason I tried the return method, but unsure how to get the updated value outside.

Comment: There is a simple way change  `REGION_ID` to `let` instead of `const`, and just assign the value in the subscribe, but... How would you know that the subscribe happened, and that the outside REGION_ID variable was updated? Why not just run the code that needs REGION_ID in the subscribe callback?

Comment: i tried the following `let Updated = store.subscribe(() => {
  let REGION_ID = store.getState();
})` but that returns the unsubscribe method. My main problem is trying to get the state to the services component in `export default new NetworkService();` but `this.props` returns undefined so i tried subscribe but I am having issue with that too.

Comment: `let REGION_ID; store.subscribe(() => { REGION_ID = store.getState(); });` - You'll have an access to `REGION_ID` outside of subscribe, but you won't know when it's ready/updated. You should open another question with your full use case. I think your solution is wrong.

Comment: Yeah I think the way I'm fetching the state is incorrect, I opened another question and I was told to look at redux thunk middleware